# XSLT + XPath: usage of id and id-ref attributes

Tags: xslt, xpath, xsl-fo, page-numbering, idref

I have an xsl-fo document having multiple `<page-sequences>`. Every second `<page-sequences>` element has the attribute `id="end"`. When I reference these IDs with `ref-id="end"`, how do I know which element is retrieved? Can I reference the **next** element having that ID?

Example (my question can be seen again in the comment):

```
<fo:page-sequence id="end">
...........
</fo:page-sequence>

<fo:page-sequence>
...........
  <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="end"/>
  <!-- unfortunately, the previous element having id="ref" has been thus referenced -->
  <!-- how could I reference the next element? -->
...........
</fo:page-sequence>

<fo:page-sequence id="end">
...........
</fo:page-sequence>
```

Comment: IDs should always be unique - that's the point of IDs. Use `generate-id()` to make sure that your IDs are not rendundant.

Comment: yes, I already found that solution and it works. Can you please write this as an answer (to both my questions), so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you please write this as an answer (to both my questions), so that I can accept it?

Sure. The precondition for referring to a specific element in XSL-FO is that you have a means of identifying it *unambiguously*. The best way to do this is to use an `ID` attribute for the element you wish to identify.

An ID must consist of any sequence of alphanumerical characters and `_` (that is, its value must be a valid NCName, see [the specification here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#id)).

You can type out each ID by hand, but normally this is done with `xsl:generate-id()` (wich is a function of XSLT, not XSL-FO). `generate-id()` automatically ensures that the IDs are unique throughout a document.

Note that `generate-id()` actually generates an ID for either the current template match or the node that is being processed in an iteration of `xsl:for-each`.

You can put an ID on every element in XML and referring to something by ID is therefore possible for any element in XSL-FO.